# How graph databases store data to a persistent storage?

Tags: database, graph, graph-databases, persistent-storage

How graph databases store data to a persistent storage?

PKV

Comment: What did you find out through doing your own research?  *Provide details. Share your research.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that every implementation of a graph database uses a different approach.

To take one example, look at Neo4j's [NeoStore](https://github.com/neo4j/graphdb/blob/master/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/nioneo/store/NeoStore.java) class, and the other kinds of store it refers to. It seems that Neo4j uses multiple files, each containing fixed-length records; one for nodes, one for keys of properties of nodes, one for values of properties of nodes, etc. Records in each contain indexes to refer to records in the others. It seems overcomplicated to me, but it evidently seemed like a good idea to the guys who wrote it!

Comment: Here's a blog post on this topic: [Neo4j Internals: File Storage](http://digitalstain.blogspot.com/2010/10/neo4j-internals-file-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

To know more about how OrientDB stores graphs look at: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Concepts#Storage